# How can I select only 1 element when clicked?

Tags: jquery

Say I want to click on the 3rd div and show the paragraph without interacting with the other divs but only the 3rd one and then I click on the 4th one without it interacting with nothing other than its self how would I do that because right now it's interacting with all of the divs and lets just say there is unlimited divs like this. I just want the on click to interact with itself/the div clicked on. jQuery only please.

```
#coolid p {
     display: none;
}

<div class="coolid"><p>hello</p></div>
<div class="coolid"><p>hello2</p></div>
<div class="coolid"><p>hello3</p></div>
<div class="coolid"><p>hello4</p></div>
<div class="coolid"><p>hello5</p></div>

$("#coolid").append("<div id='showpara'><a href=''>show paragraph</a></div>");
$("#showpara a").on("click", function (e) {
     $("#coolid").find("p").fadeIn();
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#showpara").hide();
})
```

Comment: Id should be unique..! and i wonder who did upvote this..?

Comment: so there isnt anyway this could be done because the loops are being echoed out @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Comment: Like @RajaprabhuAravindasamy said. If you need to group items set them with the same class. An id should always be unique.

Comment: You cannot use same id for multiple element ... and if you do so then how will jquery know which one to select for that id ;)

Comment: what about if the class is replaced with the id part @BhushanKawadkar

Comment: yeah, actually you should use class to identify group of elements

Comment: also replace `$("#coolid")` to `$(".coolid")` now that coolid is a class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three parts :

- as an id must be unique, use classes here
- use `this` in the event handler to target the clicked element
- use `closest` to get the embedding `.coolclass` element and from then find the element to show

Here's how it could be :

```
.coolclass p {
     display: none;
}

<div class="coolclass"><p>hello</p></div>
<div class="coolclass"><p>hello2</p></div>
<div class="coolclass"><p>hello3</p></div>
<div class="coolclass"><p>hello4</p></div>
<div class="coolclass"><p>hello5</p></div>

$(".coolclass").append("<div class='showpara'><a href=''>show paragraph</a></div>");
$(".showpara a").on("click", function (e) {
     $("p").hide();
     $(this).closest('.coolclass').find("p").fadeIn();
     e.preventDefault();
})
```

As a complementary note : you probably don't need to have an `a` element. A div (`.showpara`) is clickable too and you can set its style to `cursor:pointer`. This would also let you remove the `e.preventDefault()` line. After all, you don't have a link here...

Comment: i tried this very example and i cant get it to work?